# How to use Google voice typing as default IME?

Tags: android

As I know, recently Google has added Google voice typing as an IME that works offline. Is there any way I can make it the default IME for an EditText in my app ? (eg: when the EditText get focused, Google voice typing pops up instead of the default text keyboard)